# How to stop the Browser from automatically opening a new window of ad.adsmatte?

Tags: firefox, automation, advertisements

when i load the SO and when I click login it opens a new window for ad.admatte.com,when i click questions/Tags or any option available on any site like this it is automatically opening a new window and loading the ad.adsmatte.com.I don't understand whether it is a Spam/Virus/PUP

Did a full scan using the Windows Bit Defender didn't reveal anything.

Did a scan using the adwCleaner and it also didn't display anything.

Finally did the Firefix browser reset and that also didn't result any outcome

[Update]
Tried the safe mode using network but instead the os loads the safe mode using cmd prompt.

Tried the Windows Repair using the advanced settings but got Pc failed to start windows repair.

Tried the Firefox in safe mode(Add-ons disabled) and still the new window with Adsmatte.com opens for every click.

I am also facing the same issue in the [mobile](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/109816/how-to-stop-my-android-device-from-being-spammed-in-the-browser-as-well-as-in-th) as well for which they replied as the router itself is infected and I am supposed to hard reset my router for which I find it risky to do it all by myself and may end up in another situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc) If it's happening on every click your PC definitely seems infected. Try MalwareBytes.

Comment: Malware bytes never worked for me.It simply restarts the system but in the log nothing is revealed and also the problem remains the same.Had tried malware bytes for other adware's so I only use Adware cleaner.But for this even adware cleaner is not showing anything

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though you have a rather nasty plug-in or extension installed. Things to try:-

1. Start Firefox in safe mode (`firefox -safe-mode`) and see if the problem persists.
2. If safe mode stops the problem, start normally and disable all your extensions.
3. If the problem returns change all your plug-ins to **Never Activate** (note the previous state first).
4. If the problem is still there, remove Firefox completely and install from fresh.
5. Otherwise, restore plug-ins or extensions one at a time until the problem reappears, then remove the problem add-on.

Comment: When i tried the Shift+Restart and Advanced setting i choose F4 to try boot in safe mode +network but instead booted in safe mode in cmd prompt in black screen

Comment: I didn't mean to run Firefox with the operating system in safe mode: I meant to use Firefox's own safe mode, using the command above (with any necessary directory path to Firefox's location).

Comment: Thanks but it did not solve my problem.With every click it still opens ads,matte.com in a new window

Comment: Then you'll have to do a clean install from a new down-load of the latest version for your OS. But you ought to do a thorough virus scan first.

Comment: I use the bit defender and the latest malware scanner from microsft and in both there is no virus detected nor any malware so I am planning to do a scan using bit defender rescue disk but doubt that it will work.

Comment: Done with the clean installation of Mozilla firefox and still the malware is persistent

Comment: This is so difficult to understand that I did some searching and found it raised [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/625480/remove-pop-up-ad-from-ads-matte-com-malware-from-ubuntu). Whether on not you're on Linux you should read it, because the accepted answer seems to be the only possible explanation of your observations, namely, that it is an infection of your router. I've never come across this before, and I wouldn't have thought it possible.

Comment: Links provided by AFH really give good information and work. Issue is truly at router level. Before reconnecting to internet, don't forget to first reset your router, clear cache in all client apps like browsers.

Comment: Done with the reset by pressing the button at the back of the wireless router, still the adsmatte loads

Comment: Did you perform a full factory reset? This usually involves holding the reset button for an extended period, possibly at the same time as powering off/on. You need to make a note of any specific settings you have made before you do.

Comment: MY ISP is a very pathetic Government one's BSNL.In that i create a docket to raise a complaint and he called me since three days and all the time he asks only 3 questions 1) is modem all lights bliknking 2)Speed of the net 3)Is your landline working.That Nincompoop doesn't want to or doesn't know how to factory reset a modem, and also the security of the wlan is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution you can use [Bluhell Firewall 2.5.1](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bluhell-firewall/?src=api) Lightweight Ad-Blocker and Tracking/Privacy Protector by [Diego Casorran](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/user/diegocr/?src=api)

This tool successfully blocks said `adsmatte` popping up.

Go to Firefox -> Open Menu -> Add-ons -> 
Search for `'firewall'` and from the list select `'Bluhell Firewall'` to install.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:
Go to the Ethernet/Wireless settings (which ever you are using to connect to router) and select the network you are using. Then select the DNS option. Override the DNS settings provided by your ISP to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.4 (DNS Service from Google). Save it and renew your network Lease from router. Try to use the web now.

Save your ISP's DNS values somewhere incase you want to use it later.